# Not able to execute php 7.3 on apache 2.4.38

Tags: php, apache, redhat, httpd.conf

On my server (**Redhat 7.5**) I don't have internet access so I installed httpd, PHP and MySQL with its binaries.

So first I installed httpd server which installed on

```
/usr/local/apache2
```

After that, I installed PHP and MySQL which is running without any error.
I have put my PHP code in the following folder

```
/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

when I try to run HTML it's running properly but with PHP I try to execute PHP its show code instead of executing the code I tried to load from my PHP module in my httpd.conf file but I didn't find PHP module in my  **/usr/local/apache2/module** folder

Please help me I am stuck with this problem.

Comment: Well, where _is_ the apache php module?

Comment: @arkascha how to find location only this module is installed on apache2 check this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/

Comment: And... not having an internet connection is not a reason to install from "binaries", whatever that means, exactly. You should _still_ use the existing packages created specifically for your system, you simply take the files, put them in a folder that system has access to and create a file system based repository entry in the software management. Besides being able to update things later it also has the benefit that dependencies and configurations are resolved which prevents exactly those problems as you currently find yourself in...

Comment: I cannot tell you where you installed your files, sorry.